# Disjoint ERD relationship

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am little bit confused about the ERD concept. The situation is as follows.

There is an apartment complex (it has many apartments; Each of them has equipment - like air-conditioning, refrigerator, etc). I want to connect them with a 'maintenance company' entity.

Here is the way that I currently do that

```
MaintenanceCompany(M_ID(PK), .....)
MaintenanceDetail(M_Detail_ID(PK), M_ID(FK), M_Type, .....)
Apartment_Maintain(M_Detail_ID(PK/FK), Apartment_ID)
Complex_Maintain(M_Detail_ID(PK/FK), Complex_ID)
Equipment_Maintain(M_Detail_ID(PK/FK), Equ_ID)
```

I make 'disjoint' overlapping between MaintenanceDetail and Apartment_Maintain, Complex_Maintain, and Equipment Maintain. 
Is it correct?

If so, do I need to connect the relation(line) back from sup-entity (like Apartment_Maintain) back to their associate entity(like Apart)?

Comment: The functional requirements aren't clear yet. I can guess that Apartment_Maintain means actions on the apartment (in contrast to some piece of equipment), whereas Equipment_Maintain means actions on a piece of equipment. But what is Complex_Maintain? Why have MaintenanceDetail in addition to all those? Also, the notion of PK/FK is unclear: A field can be a primary or a foreign key, but not both.

Comment: Tam is not correct.  A key can easily be both PK and FK at the same time.  This is true of weak entities and it is true of intersection entities.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your proposed entities are. What is "Apartment_Maintain"? etc.

From your description, my start at a DB design would be:

```
complex (id (pk), name, ...)
apartment (id (pk), complex_id (fk), ...)
maintenance_company (id (pk), name, ...)
equipment (id (pk), apartment_id (fk), maintenance_company_id (fk), ...)
```

That is, you have Complexes. You have Apartments. Each Apartment is in a Complex, so there's a M:1 relationship. You have Maintenance_company's. You have Equipment. Each piece of Equipment is in one Apartment, so that's a M:1 relationship. Each piece of Equipment is maintained by one Maintenance_company, so that's another M:1 relationship.

I can imagine requirements that would lead to additional data needing to be kept. For example, this assumes any Maintenance_company can maintain any piece of Equipment, and that the Equipment in one Apartment might be maintained by different Maintenance_companies. Maybe Complexes have contracts with Maintenance_companies, so that if, say, Complex A has a contract with Maintenance_companies X and Y, then only X and Y can maintain equipment in Complex A. Or maybe companies only maintain certain types of equipment, like a company may maintain refrigerators but not air conditioners, and you need to keep track of what each company maintains and what each piece of equipment is. Etc.